# how to insert an object into grep function

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is a way to insert an object into `grep` function. See below

```
numb <- c(20, 25, 3, 5)
age = 3
  if(age%in%numb){
  length(grep("[Aa]ge: age$", agr, value=T))
} else{
  print(NULL)
}
```

Basically I want to insert the object `age` into `age` variable in `grep` function. I ask this because I have some many `age` objects to test (for example `age = 20`, `age = 25` and so on) and don't want to write a separate `grep` function for each.

Thanks

Comment: You should tell us what language you're programming in - is this R?

Comment: Please use the tags for the programming language (and framework) and remove the [object] and [grep] tags.

Comment: sorry my bad. Edited...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `paste0`, e.g.:

```
grep(paste0("[Aa]ge: ", age, "$"), agr, value=TRUE))
```

Or `sprintf`, e.g.:

```
grep(sprintf("[Aa]ge: %s$", age), agr, value=TRUE))
```

Another way would be to use regular expressions (see `?regex`):

```
grep("[Aa]ge: [0-9]+$", agr, value=TRUE)
```

Comment: Worked. Very clear solutions to my problem. I liked the first one though..cheers...

Answer (score 2):

If you goal is to count the matches of the ages specified in `numb` in the strings in `agr`, you can use this approach:

```
# an example vector
agr <- c("Age: 23", "age: 20", "age: 5", "Age: 20", "age: 3")

numb <- c(20, 25, 3, 5)

# create regex pattern
pattern <- paste0("[Aa]ge: (", paste(numb, collapse = "|"), ")$")
# [1] "[Aa]ge: (20|25|3|5)$" 

# count values
table(factor(sub(".* (\\d+)$", "\\1", grep(pattern, agr, value = TRUE)), 
             levels = numb))

# 20 25  3  5 
#  2  0  1  1
```